# Deploying Angular-fullstack on Heroku: problems adding modules

Tags: angularjs, heroku, module, mean-stack, yeoman-generator

I have used generator-angular-fullstack, and I have deployed on Heroku and all works. But I have tried to add some module (angular-bootstrap), and when I try to deploy on Heroku I have this problem:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <         8e80b874.vendor.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <         e1807e47.scripts.js:1
```

These are my steps to deploy on Heroku (the first time):

```
>> grunt build
>> cd dist
>> git push heroku master
>> heroku ps:scale web=1
>> heroku config:add NODE_ENV=production
>> heroku open
```

These are my steps to update my project on Heroku:

```
>> grunt build
>> cd dist
>> git commit -m "commit coment"
>> git push heroku master
>> heroku open
```

The problem is when I try to add some module in my angular project ('ui-router','ui.bootstrap'), in local works perfectly but when I deploy on Heroku I have the problem:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <         8e80b874.vendor.js:1

I have tried to set the paht in heroku:

```
heroku config:set NODE_PATH=lib
```

and force to add the lib folder inside my dist folder

```
git add -f lib/
```

I am lost... Any idea??
Thx

Comment: the "<" is due to express config sending the index.html on all unfound requests. I guess "8e80b874.vendor.js" is not present on your dist folder, or index.html references the wrong vendor file path

Comment: I think you need to `git add .` before you commit in `dist/`. Also, did you install those modules with `bower install --save`?

Comment: Thanks. It was a bug in this version of generator. I have moved to mean.io :p

Comment: What was the bug? The [git add requirement](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/65) is a known issue, and all it requires is a `grunt release` task to be written (or PR'd in :)